# Actual definition of $\sigma$ algebra generated by information available up to time t-1 in ARCH, GARCH models

Tags: mathematical-statistics, garch, conditional-expectation, sigma-algebra, conditional-variance

I'm trying to figure out the proper mathematical definition in sigma-algebra generated by infinite past in ARCH, GARCH type models.

Let $\epsilon_t = \sqrt{h_t} z_t $, where $z_t$ $i.i.d$ random variable with E($z_i$)=0 and  E($z_i^2$)=1.

Conditional variance of $\epsilon_t$ is  $E[\epsilon_t^2|\mathcal{F}_{t-1}]$ = $h_t$, where $\mathcal{F}_{t-1}$ is the set of information available up to time t-1, which a sigma field generated by $\{\epsilon_{t-1}, \epsilon_{t-2}....\}$

In most of the ARCH GARCH type papers, it is simply mentioned as the **information set available up to time $t-1$**. Another paper mentioned it is the set of information generated by all past linear functions.

How can I properly define this $\sigma$ algebra generated by infinite past relating to the random variables?

What I meant by infinite past ->
In these arch-type models, $\mathcal{F}_{t-1}$ is given as information available up to time ${t-1}$, $\{\epsilon_{t-1}, \epsilon_{t-2}....\}$.Because in ARCH($\infty$) infinity formwe can write any conditional variance of a GARCH type model as follows.

$h_t = \text{constant} + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \theta_i \epsilon_{t-i}^2 \quad \theta_i \geq 0, all \quad i  $.

So it would depend on this infinite past. But in reality, this would be whatever the information available. I don't if this helps but in simulations and parameter estimations using methods such as MLE we usually assume these required past lag information to be zeros to get it started.

I understand the following concepts What is a sigma-algebra, Borel sigma-algebra. But having a hard time connecting the dots.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "generated by infinite past."

Comment: I'll add it now.